# R optimize code: find most common itemsets/substitute products

Tags: r, optimization

I have a table consisting of two variables: product-id and customer-id.  Any combination of these two variables can occur multiple times (cid 'd' can be linked to pid '3' more than once).  What I am trying to achieve is to identify substitute pids for every pid in my data.table.  So, taking a look at pid='5' I can identify three distinct cids (a,c,d). in my next step I am looking for the pid(s) that share(s) as many cids with pid='5' as possible.  In this case the pid I am looking for is '10' which is linked to the same cids (a,c,d) as pid '5'.

The following piece of code works (fine) for small tables, but takes forever when I run it on a large table (3.000 pids, 900.000 cids, 4.000.000 rows). So I am looking for a way to optimize my code (or to replace it with a better one).

```
# load packages
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# create data.table
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(cbind(sample(1:10,20,replace=T),sample(c("a","b","c","d"),20,replace=T)))                                               
colnames(dt) <- c("pid", "cid")

# find substitutes
sub <- lapply(unique(dt$pid), function(f) {
    dt[,list(cid_freq=sum(unique(cid) %in% unique(dt$cid[dt$pid==f]))),by=pid] %>%
        subset(pid!=f,select=c("pid","cid_freq")) %>%
        setkey() %>%
        unique() %>%
        .[order(-cid_freq)[1],] %>%
        cbind(f,.)
})
```

---

I found kind of a (simple four-step) solution to my problem:

1. I cleaned my data (and deleted all the redundant information. As I was interested in the distinct number of cids connected to a specific pid, I could delete all duplicate rows.
2. Before looking into my data I reduced it to the relevant rows instead of looking at the whole dataset (only rows that contained the same cids as my source-pid).
3. As the substitute has to be different from the source-pid, I could delete rows referring to the source-pid.
4. working with a clean data set I could simply count the occurences of each pid, which directely referred to the number of shared cids with the source-pid.

Where my original code took more than 8 hours (at this point I canceled the operation),the executiontime could be reduced to 13 minutes by using the new code.

```
# create data.table
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(cbind(sample(1:3000,4000000,replace=T),sample(1:900000,4000000,replace=T)))                                               
colnames(dt) <- c("pid", "cid")

# find substitutes
sub <- lapply(unique(dmmy$pid),function(f){
    filter <- (dmmy$cid %in% dmmy$cid[dmmy$pid==f])&(dmmy$pid!=f)
    dmmy[filter] %>%
        .[,list(KDN_ANZ=.N),by=pid] %>%
        setorder(-KDN_ANZ) %>%
        .[1] %>%
        set_colnames(c("sub_pid","sub_cid")) %>%
        cbind(f)
})
sub <- data.table(matrix(unlist(sub),ncol=3,byrow=T)) %>%
    set_colnames(c("sub_pid","sub_cid","pid"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried working with a distance matrix?

```
dt2 <- dcast(dt, pid~cid)
m <- as.matrix(dt2[,-1,with=F])
rownames(m) <- dt2$pid
d <- dist(m, meth="bin")
as.matrix(d)[, "5"]
#         1        10         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9 
# 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.5000000
```

In this case, `10` has a maximum similarity/minimum distance of `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your approach, but i get an error message when i am trying to execute it with my real data. I think that's because my table is too big (3.000 pids, 900.000 cids) and the process is exceeding R's memory limits.

Comment: What's the error message? You could provide the code to generate an artificial dataset of that size to check whether it's the size...

Comment: I recieved the following error: "Error in seq_len(n) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer"
Anyways, I think I found a way to work around the code optimization problem by simply cleaning my data before I start working with it. I added the 'solution' to my original post.